# How to write and run unit tests in the same file as the code with Jest and typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've tried `jest-same-file-tests` but it's not working and has not been updated for 2 years.

I write tests in the same file in Rustlang and I love it.

I need to do the same in typescript using Jest or any other js testing framework.

Comment: Node has its own test runner. Try to use that and wrap your tests in an env var check. https://nodejs.org/api/test.html

Comment: You may check this discussion https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/4316

Comment: @Qiulang Already checked it out. Didn't solve it too.